# Insert custom value in every array child

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this one:

```
array(
    array(
        'Category' => 'Revisiones Operativas',
         'GQ' => '0',
         'Comment' => ''
     ),
    array(
        'Category' => 'Estatus de las Revisiones Operativas',
         'GQ' => '0',
         'Comment' => ''
     ),
    array(
        'Category' => 'Tendencias OEC',
         'GQ' => '0',
         'Comment' => ''
     ),
    array(
        'Category' => 'Reportes / Returns',
         'GQ' => '0',
         'Comment' => ''
     ),
    array(
        'Category' => 'GLs Diferencias de Cajeros / ABM',
         'GQ' => '0',
         'Comment' => ''
     ),
    array(
        'Category' => 'Cuentas GL Suspenso',
         'GQ' => '0',
         'Comment' => ''
     ),
    array(
        'Category' => 'Exedentes de Efectivo',
         'GQ' => '0',
         'Comment' => ''
     ),
    array(
        'Category' => 'ACT / BF',
         'GQ' => '0',
         'Comment' => ''
     ),
    array(
        'Category' => 'Ranking de Cajeros',
         'GQ' => '0',
         'Comment' => ''
     ),
    array(
        'Category' => 'Sessiones sin PIN (%)',
         'GQ' => '0',
         'Comment' => ''
     ),
    array('Category' => 'Transacciones Invalidas',
     'GQ' => '0',
     'Comment' => ''
    )
);
```

And i need to insert a `Date` value to every array inside my array. somethin like this:

```
array(
    array(
        'Category' => 'Revisiones Operativas',
         'GQ' => '0',
         'Comment' => ''
         'Date' => '1990/12/01'
     ),
  etc...
```

How can i do it? Is there a already made function i can use or do i have to iterate the array and add it for each record?

**Update**

I have this function:

```
public function insertDate($array, $date){
    foreach($array as $arr){
        $arr['Date'] = date;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

I just wanted to know if there was a method already in php to do this

Comment: `'Date' => '1990/12/01'` will not change ?? same for all ??

Comment: Is the date always `1990/12/01`

Comment: `array_push` ?? did you tried something ??

Comment: You just loop through array element and add Date property for each

Comment: Yes, Date is going to be static

Comment: @KentV yes, i though about it. i just wanted to know if there was another way easier

Comment: Use array_map on the first index do you can handle all the elements. array_map uses a callback function to handle every element of your array. By doing that, you can add a new date field on every index. read more: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php

Comment: @IncredibleHat it is working at the moment.

Comment: @MatteusBarbosa cool, it works better that way. thanks

Comment: @IncredibleHat But im returning that referenced array and that is my new val. `$new_array = $this->insertDate($old_array, $date)`

Comment: Im wasnt changing, i was creating a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at the built-in array functions in php: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php. One that you could use is array_map:

```
<?php

$array = [
    [
        'Category' => 'Revisiones Operativas',
        'GQ' => '0',
        'Comment' => ''
    ],
    [
        'Category' => 'Estatus de las Revisiones Operativas',
        'GQ' => '0',
        'Comment' => ''
    ]
];

$newArray = array_map(function($each){
    return $each + [
        'Date' => '1990/12/01'
    ];
}, $array);

print_r($newArray);
```

The above script will give the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Category] => Revisiones Operativas
            [GQ] => 0
            [Comment] => 
            [Date] => 1990/12/01
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Category] => Estatus de las Revisiones Operativas
            [GQ] => 0
            [Comment] => 
            [Date] => 1990/12/01
        )

)
```

Best regards :)

**UPDATE**:

You can also use array_walk if you don't wanna create another array. The following script will produce the same output as above:

```
<?php

$array = [
    [
        'Category' => 'Revisiones Operativas',
        'GQ' => '0',
        'Comment' => ''
    ],
    [
        'Category' => 'Estatus de las Revisiones Operativas',
        'GQ' => '0',
        'Comment' => ''
    ]
];

array_walk($array, function(&$each){
    $each['Date'] = '1990/12/01';
});

print_r($array);
```

Comment: Cool. I just posted an update in my answer. Also, would appreciate if you accept my answer as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through each sub-array and add the `date` index to each if them.

```
<?php
$array = array(
    array(
        'Category' => 'Revisiones Operativas',
        'GQ' => '0',
        'Comment' => ''
    ),
    array(
        'Category' => 'Estatus de las Revisiones Operativas',
        'GQ' => '0',
        'Comment' => ''
    )
); // This is your array

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++) {
    // Iterate through the array and add the date index
    $array[$i]['Date'] = date('Y/m/d');
}

print_r($array); // Print the array to verify the change
```

Either call the `date` function to insert/update the current date index with the current date, or you can write static date as per what you need.